# How to add attributes to ngform object in component class

Tags: angularjs, json

My form object is JSON.Stringify(form.value) looking like this

```
"body":{
"panNo":"IRFPP1993A",
"ackNo":"123456789"
}
```

I want output like this (I want to hardcord one new value inside

```
"body":{
"requestType":"getStatus",
*panNo":"IRFPP1993A",
"ackNo":"123456789"
}
```

Please help me ...! Thanks in advance..!

Comment: post the code sample what you have tried for your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in controller

```
if(form.value){
form.value.requestType = 'getStatus';
}
```